# Using String doInBackground(String... args)

Tags: java, android, mysql, android-asynctask

I am working on saving my data to a MySQL db.  I read that you need to use a new thread to open the db.  I have seen examples for using AsyncTask.  How would I access the doInBackground method.  I have tried a variety of different method call and either get an error or the program does not use the AsyncTask.  Here is my code.  I have tried different version of AddtoSQLDB db = new AddtoSQLDB()
and CreateNewProduct cn = new CreateNewProduct().

```
public class AddToMySQLDB extends Activity {

JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

// TODO Auto-generated method stub

// url to create new product
private static String url_create_product = "http://api.androidhive.info/android_connect/create_product.php";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
static String name = "";
static String company = "";
static String timeIn = "";
static String signature;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                .permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }

}

public static void setVariable(String sDate, String visitorsName2, String visitorsCompany2, byte[] signature2) {
    name = visitorsName2;
    company = visitorsCompany2;
    timeIn = sDate;

}
class CreateNewProduct extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // getting JSON Object
        // Note that create product url accepts POST method
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("timeIn", timeIn));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("signature", signature));
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_product,
                "POST", params);

        // check log cat fro response
        Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

        // check for success tag
        try {
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // successfully created product
/*                  Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        AllProductsActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);*/

                // closing this screen

            } else {
                // failed to create product
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

}
protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
    // dismiss the dialog once done
    pDialog.dismiss();
}


protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
    // dismiss the dialog once done
    pDialog.dismiss();
}

}
```

}

Comment: why you have 2 `onPostExecute` that both is incorrect? you need override for that and delete one of them. you don't need `StrictMode.ThreadPolicy` in your code and use `execute` for running your class

Comment: One of them is commented out. I only have one in my code

Comment: you need `@Override` for that, i don't see comment or override, anyway did your problem solved ?

Comment: I am still working on it.  First time dealing with threads in Java

Comment: I figured it out, thanks for the support.  For some reason every once in a while I get a person who leaves really nasty comments.  So when someone is supportive, I thank them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `execute` your `AsyncTask`:

```
CreateNewProduct cn = new CreateNewProduct();
cn.execute(""); //pass the params you want for doInBackground here
```

Comment: Thanks, got into the function.  Now on to the next problem